# Pandas - name a column in a Series and plot it

Tags: pandas, series

With Python 2.7 and notebook, I am trying to display a simple Series that looks like:

```
year
2014    1
2015    3
2016    2
Name: mySeries, dtype: int64
```

I would like to:

1. Name the second column, I cant seem to succeed with `s.columns = ['a','b']`. How do we do this?
2. Plot the result where the years are written as such. When I run `s.plot()` I get the years as x, which is good but I get weird values:
   [image: Graph]

Thanks for the help!

If it helps, this series comes from the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=['dates'], parse_dates=True)
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['dartes']).year
df
```

which gives me:

```
    dates   year
0   2015-05-05 14:21:00     2015
1   2014-06-06 14:22:00     2014
2   2015-05-05 14:14:00     2015
```

On which I do:
`s = pd.Series(df.groupby('year').size())`

Comment: You have a `Series` so by definition it's `1-D` so you can't assign multiple values to `columns`

Comment: that makes sense :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me works cast index to string by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.astype.html):

```
print s
y
2014    1
2015    3
2016    2
Name: mySeries, dtype: int64

s.index = s.index.astype(str)
s.plot()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Still not too familiar with Pandas! :)

Answer (score 0):

just cast your index before :

```
df.set_index(df.index.astype(str),inplace=True)
```

then you will have what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I am working with a Series ('Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'). I tried doing this on the df that my series comes from, but then I dont know how to groupy the index value.